# Missing dateRange in getData request

Tags: looker-studio

I have created a connector using Google Apps Script.  It seems to be working well, though it is pulling all data multiple times.  So far, so good for the first step.

The next step was to use the dateRange parameters in my connector in conjunction with caching, but I find they are not being passed when my report calls getData.  However, when I use the Explorer, it is passing dateRange parameters, though it only seems to be the default 28 day range.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you set `dateRangeRequired` to true in the fields configuration? See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/data-studio/config#setDateRangeRequired(Boolean)

Comment: Yes, I did.  I really think it's a bug due to adding it to an old report.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is something to do with me creating a data source, and adding it to an existing report that does not react well with the dateRange.  I created a brand new report, and now it seems to be acting fine.